# iOS: Removing a reference to a deleted nib

Tags: ios, xcode

XCode / iOS noob here...

I'm working on a project where I was trying to implement a UINavigationController in my project. I wound up not being able to get it to work, so I deleted it from my project.

Now, I'm getting the following error and I can't figure out why it says I'm referencing another view controller.

```
2013-05-14 13:04:11.336 DialysisAccessTbl[1163:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <UITableView: 0x1e191600; frame = (0 20; 768 1004); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e843f50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e843710>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> is associated with <UITableViewController: 0x1e845910>. Clear this association before associating this view with <ViewController: 0x1e841030>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x33e603e7 0x3bcea963 0x33e60307 0x35cd3d53 0x35cd3c47 0x346ce7d9 0x346ca543 0x33de68a5 0x35e0be7d 0x35e0b6ff 0x35d04079 0x35c8e451 0x35cced59 0x35ccaaf5 0x35d0c1e1 0xcd82f 0x35ccfaa1 0x35ccf625 0x35cc7833 0x35c6fd1f 0x35c6f7ad 0x35c6f1ef 0x379635f7 0x37963227 0x33e353e7 0x33e3538b 0x33e3420f 0x33da723d 0x33da70c9 0x35cc646d 0x35cc32b9 0xcd523 0x3c117b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Anyone know how to clear the association the code is talking about? This is my root view controller, which should load when the app loads.

I had two views in the nib at once briefly, but deleted the extra one.

Comment: Do you have a view controller defined in the XIB and you're also loading the XIB from your view controller init method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up deleting the old nib file and creating a new one. It looks like there was some kind of hidden reference to the deleted view.

Answer (score 0):

Control Click on your DialysisAccessTbl UITableView in interface builder and delete the connection to the UINavigationController that no longer exists.

You should check out the Stanford iTunesU Course:
Coding Together: Developing Apps for iPhone and iPad (Winter 2013)      https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016